# Is it possible to HIDE enum value or name descriptions from swashbuckle documents?

Tags: swashbuckle

We use swashbuckle to generate our API's document and swagger page.
One API takes an enum as parameter, and the swagger document will generate a list of all possible enum values.

```
 PerformanceEndType (string, optional): The descriptions we put in.  ['DayEnd', 'MonthEnd', 'QuarterEnd', 'YearEnd'],
```

In the description, we have a link which shows details about the enum, so I wants to hide the enum list swashbuckle gives us.

However, seems swashbuckle doesn't have an option to turn this on and off. I checked `DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings` but that doesn't really do what I want.